# Direction Cosine axis to $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, computational-geometry

I have a cylinder axis expressed in the form of 3 Direction Cosine. I need to convert it into a full $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix in order to display it with an openGL software. Could anybody provide a pointer on this topic ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do these direction cosines specify the cylinder’s axis? Are you trying to rotate this axis to a different position?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).  The $\mathbf k$ in this context is the vector whose components are your direction cosines.

Comment: thanks! And what about the $\Theta$ angle in this case ?

Comment: @OrP It's the angle of rotation about your axis $\mathbf k$

Comment: Hmm... I suspect the OP is looking to rotate the axis of the cylinder, not rotate around the cylinder’s axis. I’ve asked for clarification.

Comment: @amd oh! I hope he responds